# Would cobalt make a moon blue?

Tags: science-based, moons, unusual-color

Would abnormally high levels of cobalt on a moon cause it to appear blue to those on the planet it orbits?

Answer (score 3):

Elemental [cobalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt) is not blue

> The free element, produced by reductive smelting, is a hard, lustrous, silver-gray metal.

If you want to have blue with cobalt, you need to have [cobalt blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_blue)

> Cobalt blue is a blue pigment made by sintering cobalt(II) oxide with alumina at 1200 °C. Chemically, cobalt blue pigment is cobalt(II) oxide-aluminium oxide, or cobalt(II) aluminate, $CoAl_2O_4$. Cobalt blue is lighter and less intense than the (iron-cyanide based) pigment Prussian blue.

or [Prussian blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue)

> Prussian blue is a dark blue pigment produced by oxidation of ferrous ferrocyanide salts. It has the chemical formula $Fe^{III}_4[Fe^{II}(CN)_6]_3$

Answering your question, if you have abnormal levels of cobalt alone you won't get any blue. If you have the right cobalt compounds you might end with a blue looking moon.

I am not sure about their stability in space conditions, though.

Comment: There are plenty of aluminum oxides on our moon.  I am sure cobalt would join the party if there were some up there.  Without a dream in its heart.  Without a love of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt occurring naturally does not appear blue.

You can see from this [picture of cobalt ore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_extraction) as well as three of the most common naturally-occurring cobalt sources on Earth, [cobaltite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobaltite), [glaucodot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaucodot), and [skutterudite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skutterudite) that none of them appear blue.